# How to search Exact string in elasticsearch DB

Tags: elasticsearch

Search string in  elastic search DB. Can any one please help to resolve this issue.

I am facing issue when I try using below snippet,

```
BoolQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
QueryBuilder qbm = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("Coloumname", "textValue");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try using matchPhrase instead of matchQuery. It should work. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html for reference

Comment: can you update the question with what kind of mapping do you have for that column?

Comment: thanks Archit Goyal, But there is no method MatchPhrase in Elasticsearch 2.4. could you please help whether MatchPhraseQuery will work?

Comment: for my scenirio is, i want to check  value of particular coloum is already exist or not. eg:consider my DB have "Scotford station". i have to check  "Scotford" string is exist.in this case MatchPhraseQuery return "Scotford" already exist. But i want to check  entire string not contain query.